# Sorting array of object based on length array inside of object

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array of object as,

```
const sampleArray = [ {name: 'Arthur',details: [ {"book":["harry pottar","lotr","something"]} ,{"book":["omega","beta","simba"]} ] },
                     {name: 'simmone',details: [ {"book":["ronjan","pirates"]} ,{"book":["musical","eskobar","elsa"]} ]} ]
```

I want output as based on total length of book, sort object.

```
O/P:  [ {name: 'simmone',details: [ {"book":["ronjan","pirates"]} ,{"book":["musical","eskobar","elsa"]} ]}, 
        {name: 'Arthur',details:  [ {"book":["harry pottar","lotr"]} ,{"book":["omega","beta","simba"]} ]} ]
```

For this I calculated the total length of each book, as,

```
const bookDetails = sampleArray.map(i => i.book);

const emptyArray = bookDetails.map(
   subarr => subarr.reduce((a, b) => a + b.book.length, 0)
);
```

It gives me the length of book as [6,5], on basis of book count how can I sort the object as:

```
O/P:  [ {name: 'simmone',details: [ {"book":["ronjan","pirates"]} ,{"book":["musical","eskobar","elsa"]} ]}, 
        {name: 'Arthur',details:  [ {"book":["harry pottar","lotr"]} ,{"book":["omega","beta","simba"]} ]} ]
```

If anyone needs any further information, please let me know

Comment: Do you want to sort `details` array or the `sampleArray`

Comment: What should be your desired result ?

Comment: I want to sort sampleArray based on total length of book for each object.

Comment: Both have 5 books, so how you have sorted accordingly in desired output

Comment: No no. Arthur has 6 and simmone has 5.

Comment: `"harry pottar","lotr", "omega","beta","simba"`. There are total 5 books

Comment: Is `harry` and `potter are separate`

Comment: No I'm sorry I made mistake. I have edited the question with 6 books

Comment: 5 and 6 are books **count** not the length of the the tittles sum !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `customized sort` to achieve this result. But it is **highly inefficient** because it is calculating the length of the books each and every time when customizing algorithm place element before and after. **Better optimized version added below.**

```js
const sampleArray = [{
    name: "Arthur",
    details: [{
        book: ["harry pottar", "lotr", "something"]
      },
      {
        book: ["omega", "beta", "simba"]
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "simmone",
    details: [{
        book: ["ronjan", "pirates"]
      },
      {
        book: ["musical", "eskobar", "elsa"]
      },
    ],
  },
];

function getBookLength(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.book.length, 0);
}

const result = sampleArray.sort((a, b) => {
  return getBookLength(a.details) - getBookLength(b.details);
});

console.log(result);
```

### FOR BETTER PERFORMANCE: It would be better to store the length of the array so that we don't have to calculate each and every time

```js
const sampleArray = [
  {
    name: "Arthur",
    details: [
      { book: ["harry pottar", "lotr", "something"] },
      { book: ["omega", "beta", "simba"] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "simmone",
    details: [
      { book: ["ronjan", "pirates"] },
      { book: ["musical", "eskobar", "elsa"] },
    ],
  },
];

const lengthDict = sampleArray.reduce((acc, { name, details }) => {
  const length = details.reduce((a, b) => a + b.book.length, 0);
  acc[name] = length;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = sampleArray.sort((a, b) => {
  return lengthDict[a.name] - lengthDict[b.name];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Performance to turn `* n` into `constant` for time complexity. That's good.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do that, then you got everything you want, but you need to understand Sorting algorithm. I see that you didn't specify the direction of the sorting, like less books first, or more book first. But suppose we need More Books first:

```
const sortedArray = array.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
    // Return less than 0 to keep elem1 before elem2
    // Return greater than 0 to put elem2 before elem1
    // Return 0 to keep as is, regarding the rest of elements
    if (elem1.length > elem2.length) {
        return -1;
    } else if (elem1.length < elem2.length) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Apply your reduce algorithm and you're good. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

this way :

```js
const sampleArray = 
  [ { name: 'Arthur', details: 
      [ { book: [ 'harry pottar', 'lotr', 'something'] } 
      , { book: [ 'omega', 'beta', 'simba'] } 
      ] } 
  , { name: 'simmone', details: 
      [ { book: [ 'ronjan', 'pirates'] } 
      , { book: [ 'musical', 'eskobar', 'elsa'] } 
  ] } ] 

const booksCnt =({details})=>details.reduce((s,{book})=>s+book.length ,0)


sampleArray.sort((a,b)=>booksCnt(a)-booksCnt(b))

console.log( sampleArray )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```

With the **decpk** optimization :

```js
const sampleArray = 
  [ { name: 'Arthur', details: 
      [ { book: [ 'harry pottar', 'lotr', 'something'] } 
      , { book: [ 'omega', 'beta', 'simba'] } 
      ] } 
  , { name: 'simmone', details: 
      [ { book: [ 'ronjan', 'pirates'] } 
      , { book: [ 'musical', 'eskobar', 'elsa'] } 
  ] } ] 

const booksCnt = ({details})=>details.reduce((s,{book})=>s+book.length ,0)

const NamesLens = Object.fromEntries(sampleArray.map(el=>([el.name,booksCnt(el)])) )

sampleArray.sort((a,b)=>NamesLens[a.name]-NamesLens[b.name] )

console.log( sampleArray )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```